# How to have link speed and transfer percentage when sending data to serial-port?

Tags: c#, serial-port, console-application, firmware

I was developing `.Net Console app` to communicate with firmware on SAS Expander card.

When I updated the firmware, the `Tera Term`'s page would show :
[image]

You can see `[4.09KB/S]` is the link speed and `71.6%` is the transfer percentage.

Here comes a question:

How to have link speed and transfer percentange on my console app?

The link speed and transfer percentage would keep changing the numbers until the data was fully received by card.

I have already added [XmodemProtocol](https://github.com/emancipatedMind/XmodemProtocol) library on my console app.

Here is my code:

```
using XModemProtocol;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;



namespace XModemProtocolExample
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
           
            
            string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            string com = "";
            Console.WriteLine("The following serial ports were found:");
            foreach (string port in ports)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(port);
                Console.WriteLine("Please choose which port name you want ?");
                com = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Clear();
            }
            SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort(com);

            mySerialPort.BaudRate = 115200;
            mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
            mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
            mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
            mySerialPort.RtsEnable = true;
            mySerialPort.DtrEnable = true;
            mySerialPort.ReadTimeout = 2000;
            mySerialPort.WriteTimeout = 1500;
            
            mySerialPort.NewLine = "\r";
            mySerialPort.Open();

            if (mySerialPort.IsOpen)
            {
                mySerialPort.Write("\r");
            }

            List<string> Commands = new List<string>();
            string command = "";
            int counter = 0;
            mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
            while (true)
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo consoleInput = Console.ReadKey();

                if (consoleInput.KeyChar == '\r')
                {
                    Commands.Add(command);
                    counter = Commands.Count - 1;
                    mySerialPort.Write(command + "\r");
                    if (command == "fwdl")
                    {
                        ClearCurrentConsoleLine();
                    }
                    if (command == "y")
                    {
                        String FileName = "";
                        OpenFileDialog openfile1 = new OpenFileDialog();
                        if (openfile1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                        {
                            FileName = openfile1.FileName;
                        }
                        if (FileName == "")
                        {
                            Console.ReadLine();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var xmodem = new XModemCommunicator();
                            mySerialPort.Close();
                            var port = new SerialPort
                            {
                                BaudRate = 115200,
                                DataBits = 8,
                                Parity = Parity.None,
                                StopBits = StopBits.One,
                                Handshake = Handshake.None,
                                PortName = com,
                                RtsEnable = true,
                                DtrEnable = true,
                                NewLine = "\r",
                            };
                            xmodem.Port = port;
                            xmodem.Data = File.ReadAllBytes(FileName);
                            xmodem.Completed += (s, e) =>
                            {
                               
                                
                                port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler2);
                                port.Write("\r");
                              
                                
                            };
                            xmodem.Aborted += (s, e) =>
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Operation Aborted.\nPress enter to exit.");
                            };

                            xmodem.StateUpdated += (s, e) =>
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(xmodem.State);
                            };

                            port.Open();

                            // Send Data.
                            xmodem.Send();
                            

                            if (xmodem.State != XModemStates.Idle)
                            {
                                xmodem.CancelOperation();
                                Console.ReadLine();
                            }
                            Thread.Sleep(10000);
                            port.Close();
                            if (!port.IsOpen)
                            {
                                mySerialPort.Open();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (command == "mfgdl")
                    {
                        ClearCurrentConsoleLine();
                    }

                    ClearCurrentConsoleLine();
                        command = "";
                }
                else if (consoleInput.Key == ConsoleKey.UpArrow)
                {
                    if ((counter >= 0) && (counter < Commands.Count))
                    {
                        ClearCurrentConsoleLine();
                        Console.Write(Commands[counter]);
                        foreach (string obj in Commands)
                        {
                            command = obj;
                        }
                        if (consoleInput.KeyChar == '\r')
                        {
                            Commands.Add(command);
                            counter = Commands.Count - 1;
                            mySerialPort.Write(command + "\r");
                            ClearCurrentConsoleLine();
                            command = "";
                        }
                    }

                    if (counter > 0)
                    {
                        counter--;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        counter = Commands.Count - 1;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    command += consoleInput.KeyChar.ToString();
                }
              
            }          
        }
        private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
             Console.Write(indata);
        }

        private static void DataReceivedHandler2(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
            Console.Write(indata);
        }

        private static void ClearCurrentConsoleLine()
        {
            int currentLineCursor = Console.CursorTop;
            Console.SetCursorPosition(6, Console.CursorTop);
            Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
            Console.SetCursorPosition(6, currentLineCursor);
        }
     
    }

}
```

What my console shows:

[image]

I could only know the xmodem's state.

I have no idea about how to build a link speed and transfer percentage.

Could [XmodemProtocol](https://github.com/emancipatedMind/XmodemProtocol) do this thing? If so, how to do that?

My Console app is using `.Net Framework 4.7.2`.

`Received xxxxxxxx Bytes` is the response from the card.

It could only come out after the data fully sent to the card(100%).

.................................................

Update1:

After adding

```
xmodem.PacketToSend += (s, e) =>
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(e.PacketToSend.Count);
                            };
```

The console shows like:

[image]

..............................................

Update2:

After I deleted

```
xmodem.PacketToSend += (s, e) =>
{
       Console.WriteLine(e.PacketToSend.Count);
};
```

, I replaced it with

```
xmodem.PacketReceived += (s, e) =>
{
      Console.WriteLine(e.PacketReceived.Count);                        
};
```

The console's result :

[image]

Why `PacketReceived` event won't fire?

Comment: Since there is a list of PacketNumber and actual data in EventArgs of [PacketToSend](https://github.com/emancipatedMind/XmodemProtocol/blob/ca0a3fe6422e2bc5d18d4a719170cc919ef51134/EventData/PacketToSendEventArgs.cs)/[PacketReceived](https://github.com/emancipatedMind/XmodemProtocol/blob/ca0a3fe6422e2bc5d18d4a719170cc919ef51134/EventData/PacketReceivedEventArgs.cs) event of XModemProtocol, if you add the size for each event, you can see how many bytes are transferred at that time?

Comment: @kunif how to add the size for each event? I only built  ``xmodem.PacketToSend += (s,e) =>{ }`` and ``xmodem.PacketReceived += (s,e) => { }`` these two event in my code. I have already used ``long length=new System.IO.FileInfo(FileName).Length`` to know the file size in bytes.

Comment: For example, you can prepare a variable for the number of bytes sent in a global location in the class, and add the value obtained by subtracting the control data and CRC/Checksum bytes from EventArgs.PacketToSend.Length for each event.

Comment: @kunif Do You mean to use  [CRCChecksumCalculator.cs ] (https://github.com/emancipatedMind/XmodemProtocol/blob/master/Calculators/CRCChecksumCalculator.cs) 's ``_currentByte``? Sorry, I am still not clear on with that.

Comment: It's the byte data that the library is currently processing, and it doesn't matter where it is in the entire file.

Comment: @kunif which event I can grub the control data? ``xmodem.PacketReceived``?Also, how to use EventArgs.PacketToSend.Length ?When I typed ``xmodem.PacketToSend.``, there is no Length option.

Comment: Please try to see if you can handle the control data. Then, since the data sent and received in EventArgs is List<byte>, you can find the size by the [Count property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.count?view=net-5.0) instead of Length.

Comment: @kunif Actually I didn't know how to pass List<byte> in my code. Sorry for that. I am new to c#.

Comment: Just use EventArgs.PacketToSend.Count instead of EventArgs.PacketToSend.Length.

Comment: @kunif I updated the question. The error shows: ``'EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'PacketToSend' ``.I use ``xmodem.EventArgs.PacketToSend.Count`` and ``EventArgs.PacketToSend.Count``.

Comment: My comment explains the concept. If your implementation is different, make the necessary modifications. For example, it seems that you are using an anonymous function for the event handler, so should `xmodem.EventArgs.` Or `EventArgs.` Be replaced with `e.`?

Comment: @kunif OK. I got the number. It is 132. But it seems different from the link speed on ``Tera Terms``. Is there something I missed?

Comment: That would be the size of one packet containing the control data. [XMODEM File Transfer Protocol](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/xmodem-file-transfer-protocol/) You need to measure and calculate the transfer speed and progress by yourself.

Comment: @kunif OK, I'll try it by myself. Another question is I add ``xmodem.PacketReceived += (s, e) =>{Console.WriteLine(e.PacketReceived.Count); }`` , this event doesn't fired what the ``README.md`` said. There is no ``Console.WriteLine(e.PacketReceived.Count)`` 's result on Console. Why is that happened?

Comment: I'm just looking at the documentation and thinking, so I don't know what the situation is. Please add it to the question or issue a new question.

Comment: @kunif I added it to the question. Please have a look.

Comment: At this stage, it looks like a debug request or a software development request that is not suitable for this site. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Even if you are not familiar with C#, you will have experience and knowledge in software development, so it is better to make full use of them and work on your own to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would like to be able to display something like this:

```
...
SenderPacketsBeginSent
PendingCompletion
Idle

Link speed: 4.09KB/s
Transfer percentage: 34%
```

Where the link speed and transfer percentage is updated in place on your console?

You can move your screen cursor using `Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setcursorposition?view=net-5.0) to move the output to the two different locations where you want to display your metrics.

The transfer completion calculation you'll need to do yourself. But that's pretty straightforward:

percentage = (total bytes transferred / file size) x 100.

So your program flow will go something like this:
in your while loop when you transfer the data you,

1. move your screen cursor to where you want to output the 'link speed' then Console.Write your current measured speed.
2. move your screen cursor to where you want to output the 'transfer percentage' then Console.Write your current calculated percentage.

Comment: OK....So how to know the link speed on serial port?